# DQL Allow Nullable Join?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

In my entity 'Item', there is an ArrayCollection property known as "products" (of Entity 'Product') that can be empty

I need all product info (empty or not) in one DQL call for the array of 'Item' entities

```
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query->select(['v', 'p'])->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
            ->join('v.products', 'p')
            ->orderBy('v.datePublished', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

The problem here, is that the only records that get returned are ones that have at least one product in them. I need to return Items that have empty products as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so.. this is all that needed to happen:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select(['v', 'p'])->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
        ->join('v.products', 'p')
        ->orderBy('v.datePublished', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

becomes

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select(['v', 'p'])->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
        ->leftJoin('v.products', 'p')
        ->orderBy('v.datePublished', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

I'm excited to get back to my life now.